# Why is the div margin taking up the whole top of my page

Tags: css

When I look at my div the whole margin takes up the top of my page instead of only taking up where it's placed at; I just noticed this when comparing to other sites. Use Chrome developer tools.

How do I get it to stop doing that and only take up the space it needs?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background: white;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id=sidebar>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </div>
  <span>hello</span>
</body>
```

Comment: If I use float it fixes it: Is that the only way?

Comment: From which space are you talking about?

Comment: When you hover over the div that holds the div; it takes up the whole top compared to just the area it's at. Use chrome dev tools and inspect it with the Ctrl+Shift+C (select an element in the page) tool, you'll see the orange box, that's margin and it takes up the whole top.

Comment: You probably want body to be the flex container...

Comment: Because with Facebook, you can see they use a flex column and it doesn't do that.

aka <div class="j83agx80 cbu4d94t buofh1pr">

Comment: again, probably because the parent is itself a flex container  ... https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/  a `display:flex` container is a block anyway, so the span can only show below it. Your code works as it should.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm going to check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the margin around all the page then you need to reset your css in the beginning like this :

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

#sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background: white;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id=sidebar>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </div>
  <span>hello</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah my new problem is, I can't use flex to do 100% height, it won't go to the bottom of my page for a "Sidebar"

Comment: dear friend, I added another answer with the fixed code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with #sidebar display: inline-flex and width: auto ?

Comment: Why does normal flex take up all the top then?

Comment: Please use the comment section to write this comment -> It's not an answer

Comment: I dont know, but i made a codepen with display: inline-flex and width: auto and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying the sidebar as "inline-block":

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background: white;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  /*\/*/
  display: inline-block;
  
}

span {
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id=sidebar>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </div>
  <span>hello</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The body element generally has an 8px margin by default in some browsers so you need to control it in your own stylesheet instead and set it to what you want. Historically some browsers used padding and some used margin and some applied them to the html element instead of body.

```
html,body{margin:0;padding:0}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it good to set margin/padding to 0 for the HTML/body or is that considered a bad thing to do for every project?

Comment: This is part of the “CSS Reset” theory which helps keep your designs consistent across browsers, a very good thing. This technique works on all browsers, so I never really considered any negatives.

Comment: Oh wow, I haven't heard about it... but I'm only in the beginning phases of learning a mix of css/html, is it good for reactive stuff or does it not affect it?

Comment: it is usually an excellent to use for reactive stuff.  It will never conflict / affect. You are free to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

check this edit on your code will make the edits you wanted:

the edits:
I added a container for the sidebar and the span , and give the same height to the body and the container div, and the important thing is to make the span height 50% because if it takes 100% will cause the space under the row because we made top 50% away from the margin.

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;

}
.row {  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
  
}
#sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background: white;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;

}

span {
  color: blue;
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
   

 <body>
  <div class="row">
   <div id=sidebar>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
   </div>
   <span>hello</span>
  </div>
</body>
```